# Hour is returning wrong with simpledateformat in US server

Tags: simpledateformat

```
String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd@HH-mm-ss").format(new Date());
```

This is returning `[2016-08-09@03-02-43]` from `Eclipse` but when deployed on server it is returning `[2016-08-09@10-02-43]`.

The local date is also in the same time zone.

I am unable to figure out why?
Could anyone please help?

Comment: i think your server is returning GMT time, if you see the difference in times its about 10 am - 3pm which is about 5 hours, the difference between greenwich mean time and IST (my assumption)

Comment: It is 3AM (US )actually.The hour (HH), using a 24-hour clock from 0 to 23. So it must be showing 7 hours ahead.

Comment: ah i see. nonetheless, the server time is not of the same timezone from where the request is made. you will need to format the time by taking into account the current locale of the device.

Comment: Its working when timezone is changed to PST. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Nice! I'm adding my comment as an answer for anyone else who encounters this issue. Would be great if you could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server timezone is probably different than from where the request is generated. That's primarily the reason for the difference in the time logs that you see. UTC or PST time zone.

```
[2016-08-09@03-02-43]
```

whereas, the following timestamp is IST.

```
[2016-08-09@10-02-43]
```